# MPI_Sendrecv_replace gets blocked

Tags: mpi, matrix-multiplication

I am working on a code that implements Cannon matrix multiplication algorithm.
Cannon's algorithm is described in the following fragment in pseudocode:

1. Executed in parallel:

- circular movement with i positions to the left ofsub matrices Ai,x
- circular movement with j positions upwards of submatrices Bx,j

2. for k = 0 to n/p-1
   Executed in parallel:

- Ci,j = Ci,j + Ai,j * Bi,j
- circular movement with 1 position to the left of sub matrices Ai,x
- circular movement with 1 position upwards of
  sub matrices Bx,j

However my code seems to get blocked in the for loop after sending the submatrix B.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    
        read_input_files(argc, argv);
        int rank, size, i, j, shift;
        //print_matrix(N, A, 0);
        //print_matrix(N, B, 0);
        //print_matrix(N, AB);
    
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
        MPI_Comm comm;
        MPI_Status status;
        int left, right, up, down;
        int shiftsource, shiftdest;
        int dims[2] = { 0, 0 }, periods[2] = { 1, 1 }, coords[2];
    
        MPI_Dims_create(size, 2, dims);
    
        MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dims, periods, 1, &comm);    
        MPI_Cart_coords(comm, rank, 2, coords);
    
        MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 1, -1, &right, &left);
        MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 0, -1, &down, &up);
        //printf("%d --- %d %d %d %d.\n", rank, right, left, up, down);
    
        if (dims[0] != dims[1]) {
            printf("The number of processors must be a perfect square.\n");
            if (rank == 0)
                printf("The number of processors must be a perfect square.\n");
            MPI_Finalize();
            return 0;
        }
    
        int block_size = N / sqrt(size);
        cout << rank << " : dims " << dims[0] << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
        int* A_sub = make_sub(A, rank, block_size, size);
        int* B_sub = make_sub(B, rank, block_size, size);
        int* AB_sub = (int*)calloc(block_size * block_size, sizeof(int));
        //print_submatrix(block_size, A_sub, rank);
    
        cout << rank << " : coords " << coords[0] << " * " << coords[1] << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
        MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 0, -coords[0], &shiftsource, &shiftdest);
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(A_sub, block_size * block_size, MPI_INT, shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm, &status);
        cout << rank << " : MPI_Sendrecv_replace A_sub " << endl;
    
        //print_submatrix(block_size, A_sub, rank);
    
        MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 1, -coords[1], &shiftsource, &shiftdest);
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(B_sub, block_size * block_size, MPI_INT, shiftdest, 1, shiftsource, 1, comm, &status);
        cout << rank << " : MPI_Sendrecv_replace B_sub " << endl;
        
        for (shift = 0;shift < dims[0];shift++) {
            for (i = 0;i < block_size;i++) {
                for (j = 0;j < block_size;j++)
                {
                    for (k = 0;k < block_size;k++) {
                        AB_sub[i * block_size + j] += A_sub[i * block_size + k] * B_sub[k * block_size + j];
                    }
                }
            }
    
            if(shift == dims[0]-1) print_submatrix(block_size, AB_sub, rank);
    
            MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 1, 1, &left, &right);
            MPI_Sendrecv_replace(A_sub, block_size * block_size, MPI_INT, left, 1, right, 1, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            cout << rank << " : MPI_Sendrecv_replace A " << endl;
    
            MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 0, 1, &up, &down);
            MPI_Sendrecv_replace(B_sub, block_size * block_size, MPI_INT, up, 1, down, 1, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            cout << rank << " : MPI_Sendrecv_replace B " <<endl;
            
        }
    
        //print_matrix(N, AB, rank);
        //cout << rank << " : coords " << coords[0] << " * " << coords[1] << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    
        MPI_Gather(&AB_sub, block_size*block_size, MPI_INT, AB, N*N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
        MPI_Finalize();// MPI_Comm_free(&comm);  Free up communicator
    
        //print_matrix(N, AB, 0);
        return 0;
    }
```

read_input_files() is a function that reads the 2 matrices in files give as cmd line args.

A matrix after reading file:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35
```

B matrix after reading file:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35
```

N is the size of matrix, N is 6 in this case.

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve] and indicates how many MPI tasks you are using. Note you should `MPI_Gather(AB_sub, ...)`

Comment: I have updated the question with input examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your call `MPI_Cart_shift(comm, 1, -coords[1],` has a strange shift parameter: you're shifting by something depending on the coordinate. That should probably be `MPI_Cart_shift(comm,1,-1`.